# Table causes horizontal scrollbar to appear on mobile device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My issue is this piece of code:

```
        <form method="post" name="myform" class="donate-form">

                        <table class="donate-table">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="logo.png"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donation Amount"> 
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="check">
                                        <input  name="os0" type="radio" value="5.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$5" id="textBlock">$5.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input  name="os0" type="radio" value="25.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$25" id="textBlock">$25.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input name="os0" type="radio" value="10.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$10" id="textBlock">$10.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input name="os0" type="radio" value="Other" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="other" id="textBlock">Custom</label>
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

The issue is within the table "donate-table" closer to the bottom. I have 4 radio buttons, 5,10,25, and other, I want these radio-buttons to be displayed in 2 rows with 2 columns. On chrome (fullscreen) everything looks perfect no horizontal scroll bar and all radio buttons are looking okay but when I shrink the window to be as small as possible or when I use my mobile device the radio buttons get cut off and on my smartphone a horizontal scrollbar appears (I know the issue is because of a smaller screen size but I can't seem to fix it) When I delete 3 radio buttons and only have 1 the problem is gone. How can I fix this so I can display 4 radio buttons without a horizontal scrollbar appearing? I have looked and tried overflow-x:hidden; and some other suggested solutions but none work.
Anyone have a fix? Thank you in advance.

Here is my CSS code if needed:

```
 .donations{
   margin-top: 15%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

 .checkboxgroup {
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 150px;
  }
 .checkboxgroup label {
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through the code `comments`. Hope this will help you.

`01. Replace all <th></th> with <td></td>`

`02. /* use .donate-table instead of .donations */`

`03. /* move min-height property to parent class (means .donate-table class) */`

```css
/* use .donate-table instead of .donations */
.donate-table{
   margin-top: 15%;
   overflow: hidden;
   width:100%;
   min-width:160px;
   max-width:500px;
  }

/* move min-height property to parent class (means .donate-table class) */
 .checkboxgroup {
   display: inline-block;
  }
 .checkboxgroup label {
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<form method="post" name="myform" class="donate-form">

                        <table class="donate-table">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cpp_header_image" value="logo.png"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Donation Amount"> 
                            <tr>
                                <td> <!-- Replace all <th></th> with <td></td> -->
                                    <div class="check">
                                        <input  name="os0" type="radio" value="5.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$5" id="textBlock">$5.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input  name="os0" type="radio" value="25.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$25" id="textBlock">$25.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input name="os0" type="radio" value="10.00" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="$10" id="textBlock">$10.00</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="checkboxgroup">
                                        <input name="os0" type="radio" value="Other" id="radio"> 
                                        <label  for="other" id="textBlock">Custom</label>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: That fixed the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome You Dear :).